# find the Vertical asymptotes of function $f$ :

Tags: calculus

find the Vertical asymptotes of function $f$ :

$$f(x)=\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{x(2x-1)^2(x-2)}}$$

---

My Try :

$$g(x):=\sqrt{x(2x-1)^2(x-2)}$$

$$f(x)\to \infty : g(x)\to 0$$

So we have :

$$g(x)\to 0$$

$$x\to 0$$

$$x \to \dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$x \to 2$$

Thus Answer is $x =0, \dfrac{1}{2},  2$

it is right ?

Comment: is this $$f(x)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x(2x-1)(x^2+x+1)}}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  I edited

Comment: why don't you simplify $x+x+1$ to $2x+1$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner . ohhhhhhhhh im sorry !

Answer (score 1):

your term $$\sqrt{x(2x-1)^2(x-2)}$$ is equal to zero if $x=0$or $x=\frac{1}{2}$ or $x=2$ these are the vertical asymptotes
you must observe that we have $x>2$ or $x<0$ and we must take the limit for $x$ tends to zero from the left, in this sense is $x=0$ not a vertical asymptote and $x=\frac{1}{2}$ also not

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x(2x-1)^2(x-2)}}$$

To have a vertical asymptote, it's not sufficient that denominator is zero.

The value must be in the domain, first of all.

In this case the domain is given by the $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x(x-2)>0$

that is $x<0\lor x>2$, so $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is not in the domain, and cannot be an asymptote.

Second to have $x=c$ vertical asymptote we must have

$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=\infty$$
positive or negative $\infty$

In this case $f(x)$ can be written as

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x(2x-1)^2(x-2)}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{|2x-1|\sqrt{x-2}}$$
Therefore the only vertical asymptote is $x=2$

Hope it helps

$$...$$
[image]